Как в javascript вызвать приватный метод класса, используя его имя из строки
class Bar {
    static publicMethod() {
        let string = 'baz';
        Bar[methodName](); //это работает, всё ок

        string = 'foo';
        // а как тут вызвать Bar.#foo() ?
    }
    static baz() {
        ////
    }
    static #foo() {
        ////
    }
}


Из того, что видел... Везде используется обращение this.#nameMethod. this['#nameMethod'] не работает...

Я вижу только два варианта: либо делать проверку и вызывать напрямую (if (string === '#foo') this.#foo()), либо через eval, но так делать не стоит, поскольку это очень небезопасная функция, особенно если вы будете получать строку извне. лучше используйте первый вариант

Главный вопрос зачем???  Разработчики спецификации специально не стали давать такую возможность, потому что это не имеет смысла

Не совсем понятно что вы хотите получить в итоге.
Если вы работаете внутри статичного метода, то вы можете вызывать через внутренний контекст другие статичные методы в том числе и приватные.
Когда вы используете запись вида Bar["#foo"](), то вам выдаст ошибку о невозможности получить доступ к приватному методу или переменной.
Используйте вызов статичных методов или функций которые не являются приватными по названию класса:
// WORK
Bar.publicMethod();
Bar.baz()

// DON'T WORK
Bar.#foo();

Используйте вызов статичных приватных методов функций или переменных внутри класса для соблюдения созданных правил.
static publicMethod() {
  // Work
  this.baz();
  this.#foo();
  Bar.baz();

  // Don't work
  Bar.#foo();
}

Рабочий пример:


class Bar {
  static publicMethod() {
    // Work
    this.baz();
    this.#foo();
  }
  static baz() {
    console.log("baz");
  }
  static #foo() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
}

Bar.publicMethod(); // Work

Bar.baz(); // console.log("baz")
// Bar.#foo(); // Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#foo' must be declared in an enclosing class



